# Monogame isometric hex coordinate

Tags: c#, coordinates, monogame, isometric

I am currently developing a small **hexagonal game in isometric view (30°)**

After successfully creating a coordinate system (offset and cube) I want to retrieve the coordinates based on my mouse position (x, y).

I've been using Amit's tutorial ([redblobgames.com](http://redblobgames.com)) so far, but after trying for 2 days, I an unable to get the coordinates.

Does anyone have any idea?

Screenshots :

[hexIso1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POPsC.png)
[hexIso2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThHZY.png)

Comment: Can you show us some relevant code and what you have tried already? (does not matter if it doesn't work. pseudo code is also fine)